# Обращение к индексу в объекте

Tags: javascript

Заполняю объект определенным значениями, далее обращаюсь к определенному индексу в объекте и меняю ему значение, но меняется значения в индексе к которому обращаюсь и в последнем. Не могу понять в чем проблема?

```js
    var values = {};
    
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var mins = { 'min' : 0, 'max' : 0 }
     mins.min = i;
        mins.max = i;
    
     values[i] = mins;
    }
    
    console.log(values);
    
    mins.min = 10;
    mins.max = 20;
    
    values[2] = mins;
    
    console.log(values);

    // 0: {min: 0, max: 0}
    // 1: {min: 1, max: 1}
    // 2: {min: 10, max: 20}
   // 3: {min: 3, max: 3}
   // 4: {min: 10, max: 20}
```

Comment: или я не туда смотрю или проблема не воспроизводится. Уточните

Comment: а, ну так получается, что  Вы присваиваете полю 2, объект `mins`, который является значением последнего поля. В данном случае - 4

Comment: Так до присвоения индексу 2 значения, 4-ый равен 4,4 после итерации в цикле. Разве нет? я 4-ый индекс вообще не трогаю

Comment: делая такую запись `mins.min = 10`, Вы же не создаете новый объект, а работаете с тем, который объявили раньше.... а по такому случая вот - https://learn.javascript.ru/object-reference

Comment: Верно я обращаюсь к свойствам min, max объекта и переприсываиваю им значения

Comment: вы же еще не успели прочитать информацию по ссылке, которую я Вам дал.... и осознать ее...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После выполнения цикла переменная mins определена и ссылается на последний объект, затем вы в нем меняете значения и присваиваете этот же объект в массив по второму индексу.

Таким образом второй и пятый элементы массива ссылаются на один и тот же объект

Я бы сделал как-то так :

```js
 var values = {};
    
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  values[i] = {min : i, max : i };
}

console.log(values);

values[2] = { min : 0, max : 0 };

console.log(values);
```

PS: в выводе в консоль результата работы вашего снипета видно что в массиве содержатся ссылки на один и тот же объект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а я бы использовал let)

Comment: Вижу спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Теперь работает. Не стоит объявлять постоянно новый объект в цикле, объявите его один раз, перед началом цикла.

```js
var values = {};
var mins = { 'min' : 0, 'max' : 0 }
    
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

  values[i] = {
    'min': i,
    'max': i
  };
}

console.log(values);

mins.min = 10;
mins.max = 20;

values[2] = mins;

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Спасибо теперь разобрался